# Attempting to show $P(|S_n| <1)$ for a martingale $(S_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, martingales

[image]

Now, I am stuck on the last part of the question. I managed to find the solutions, but I don't udnerstand them completely.
[image]

What I don't understand is: How they got that indicator function, and why they are using double expectation to calculate the probability. I'd appreciate it if someone coudl help out, thanks.

Comment: The solution you found somewhere seems more complicated than necessary. Note that the build-up questions show that $S_n\in\{a(S_{n-1}),b(S_{n-1})\}$ almost surely for two deterministic functions $a$ and $b$ such that $a_n(x)\cdot b_n(x)=-1$ and $a_n(x)\ne\pm1\ne b_n(x)$ for every $x\ne0$. Thus, $|a(S_{n-1})|<1<|b(S_{n-1})|$ (or the other way round) and the proof is complete since $P(S_n=a(S_{n-1}))=P(S_n=b(S_{n-1}))=\frac12$.

Comment: @Did how did you get $P(S_n = a(S_{n-1}) = 1/2$?

Comment: Note that $a(x),b(x)=x\pm\sqrt{1+x^2}$ hence $[S_n=a(S_{n-1}]=[X_n=+1]$ or $[S_n=a(S_{n-1}]=[X_n=-1]$, depending on the choice of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can show the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is such that:

1. $\forall x,f(x)\geq 1$. Also $f(x)=1\iff x=0$.
2. $x< 0 \implies 0<x+f(x)<1$. Similarly $x>0\implies -1<x-f(x)<0$

Second, to prove
$$
1_{\{|S_n|<1\}}=\frac{-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1}{2} 
$$
note this: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1}{2} =1 & \iff & -X_nsign(S_{n-1})=1\\
& \iff & (X_n=-1\:\wedge\:S_{n-1}>0)\vee(X_n=1\:\wedge\:S_{n-1}<0)\\
& \implies & |S_n|<1
\end{eqnarray}

(the last line is consequence of the second property of $f(x)$ previously mentioned). On the other hand
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1}{2} =0 & \iff & -X_nsign(S_{n-1})=-1\\
& \iff & (X_n=-1\:\wedge\:S_{n-1}<0)\vee(X_n=1\:\wedge\:S_{n-1}>0)\\
& \implies & |S_n|>1
\end{eqnarray}

(the last line is consequence of the first property of $f(x)$ previously mentioned).

Third, by the previous point
$$
\mathbb{P}[|S_n|<1]=\mathbb{E}[1_{\{|S_n|<1\}}]=\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2]
$$
in other words, computing the desired probability is the same as computing 
$
\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2]
$. Computing this directly looks pretty tedius (you'd need to compute the distribution of $X_nsign(S_{n-1})$, etc). Luckily, using the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), the conditional expectation 
$$
Y_{n-1}:=\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]
$$
verifies:
$$
\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{n-1}]
$$

Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}[|S_n|<1]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]
$$
and since $S_{n-1}\in \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ and $X_n$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}=\sigma(X_1,...,X_{n-1})$, by [properties of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) we deduce 
$$
Y_{n-1}=\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n]sign(S_{n-1})+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
hence 
$$
\mathbb{E}[(-X_nsign(S_{n-1})+1)/2]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{n-1}]=1/2
$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I am still fairly stumped as to why the double expectation gives you the probability required, could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @lampj20la You are welcome. Yes. I've decided to modify the answer to show that the probability equals the double expectation, rather than answering as a comment, as it would be a rather lengthy comment.